# Is there a way to creating histogram with matplotlib without duplicate from the code snippet below?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

**Is there a way to creating histogram with matplotlib without duplicate from the code snippet below, using for-loop?**

> Here is the code to plot different graph for histogram.

````
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))

#Create first histogram subplot of top 10 vs bottom 90 'budget_adj' distribution 
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax.hist(first_10['budget_adj'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5, label = 'Top 10');
ax.hist(bottom_90['budget_adj'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5 , label = 'Bottom 90');
ax.set_title('Top 10 vs Bottom 90 budget_adj distribution');
ax.set_xlabel('Budget Adjusted (e+8)')
ax.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
ax.legend();

#Create second histogram subplot of top 10 vs bottom 90 'runtime' distribution 
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax2.hist(first_10['runtime'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5, label = 'Top 10');
ax2.hist(bottom_90['runtime'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5 , label = 'Bottom 90');
ax2.set_title('Top 10 vs Bottom 90 runtime distribution');
ax2.set_xlabel('Runtime')
ax2.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
ax2.legend()

#Create third histogram subplot of top 10 vs bottom 90 'vote average' distribution 
ax3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax3.hist(first_10['vote_average'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5, label = 'Top 10');
ax3.hist(bottom_90['vote_average'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5 , label = 'Bottom 90');
ax3.set_title('Top 10 vs Bottom 90 vote_average distribution');
ax3.set_xlabel('Vote Average')
ax3.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
ax3.legend()

#Create third histogram subplot of top 10 vs bottom 90 'popularity' distribution 
ax4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
ax4.hist(first_10['popularity'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5, label = 'Top 10');
ax4.hist(bottom_90['popularity'], normed = True, alpha = 0.5 , label = 'Bottom 90');
ax4.set_title('Top 10 vs Bottom 90 popularity distribution');
ax4.set_xlabel('Popularity')
ax4.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
ax4.legend()

plt.tight_layout() #Prevents subplots labels from overlapping ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of the code is repeated, so it can be put inside a loop. First, we can create the axes with:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
```

This will create a `figure` and a 2x2 `np.ndarray` with four subplots. We can loop through this array and access all the individual axes. The other unique features of every plot are the keys and the xlabels, so we can construct lists for those:

```
keys = ['budget_adj', 'runtime', 'vote_average', 'popularity']
x_labels = ['Budget Adjusted (e+8)', 'Runtime', 'Vote Average', 'Popularity']
```

To loop through `axes`, `keys` and `x_labels`, `zip()` can be used:

```
for ax, key, x_label in zip(axes.flatten(), keys, x_labels):
    ax.hist(first_10[key], normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Top 10')
    ax.hist(bottom_90[key], normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Bottom 90')
    ax.set_title(f'Top 10 vs Bottom 90 {key} distribution')
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
    ax.legend()
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
keys = ['budget_adj', 'runtime', 'vote_average', 'popularity']
x_labels = ['Budget Adjusted (e+8)', 'Runtime', 'Vote Average', 'Popularity']

for ax, key, x_label in zip(axes.flatten(), keys, x_labels):
    ax.hist(first_10[key], normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Top 10')
    ax.hist(bottom_90[key], normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Bottom 90')
    ax.set_title(f'Top 10 vs Bottom 90 {key} distribution')
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalised Sample')
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
```

Hope this helps!